# how to store uislider values for 10 seconds on a nsmutablearray on iOS and how to load the nsmutablearray values to other uislider

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, uislider

I know that I have to convert uislider value to nsnumber object and store it in the array but what is the required loop to store and load the values for a time, example 10 seconds?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do something like this:

```
 NSMutableArray *arrayWithSomeValues=[NSMutableArray array];
 // My options is the actual option from your slider. 
 [arrayWithSomeValues addObject:myOption];
 // ...
 // After adding everything you need
 // ...
 [self performSelector:@selector(switchValues:) withObject:arrayWithSomeValues afterDelay:10.0];
```

The switchValues method will then receive your array, and there you can do what you want with them.